# How to add a user from guest (sudo not working)

Tags: permissions, sudo, guest-session

I'm new to Ubuntu and I currently have a virtualbox set up running Ubuntu. I noticed that it's running a guest user and I am not able to run certain commands.

Any time I try to run a ***sudo*** command like ***sudo apt-get update*** it gives me a ***sudo: unable to change to root gid: Operation not permitted***

I've tried adding a user from here but I've been seeing that it requires sudo commands. Any help in creating a new user so I can have permissions?

Comment: You need to log in to a regular user account (with admin privileges) to use sudo. Such a user should have been created when you installed Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi Gunnar - I am trying to but only see two options Guest Session and osboxes.org, which wouldn't be me. I'm trying to figure out how to create a userID now but the only way I can access my Ubuntu machine is through the guest session...any pointers? Thanks for the help gunnar!

Comment: If the install didn't give you the opportunity to add a user, then `osboxes.org` almost certainly *is* you (or at least it's the default user account for the image you installed) - see 'What are the credentials for virtual-machine image?' in the [osboxes FAQs](http://www.osboxes.org/faqs/)

Answer (score 2):

The Guest account is very restricted.  It doesn't have access to making any permanent changes.  When you installed Ubuntu it would have required you to create at least one userID.  That user ID wold by default have access to commands such as `sudo` and greater access for making changes to the system.

So the bottom line is, you can't run `sudo` from the guest account.

---

**If your userID is hidden for what ever reason log in via the console**

Use this to get a command console.  Then type in the username that was used to install ubuntu.  That will give you the `sudo` command.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I am aware that I am heavily restricted and don't have the appropriate perms currently -- what I'm trying to figure out is how to sign in with a userID. 

Looks like the only options available is guest session or osboxes.org which would not be me. Hrmmm - those definitely aren't mine...any suggestions?

Comment: Look at the bottom of my answer... updated.  That is the steps  for logging under the userID you used for installing Ubuntu.